# Problems adding "AudioStream" Plugin to PhoneGap 1.7 Project

Tags: ios, xcode, plugins, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Good evening,

I just wanted to add the "AudioStream" plugin (https://github.com/liip/phonegap-plugins-audiostream) to my Project.

With this plugin you can set current title informations to the iOS lockscreen.

But when I try to compile I get this error:

`/Users/~/Documents/Arbeit/Rhythm/Source/iOS App/Project/Rhythm/Rhythm/AudioStream.h:9:9: 'PhoneGapCommand.h' file not found`

I renamed `PhoneGapCommand.h`to `Cordova/CDVPlugin.h` but then I get even more errors.

Could somebody change these pluginfiles, so that they just work and post them here?

I'd apreciate it very much!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this project has the updated native & Javascript code: https://github.com/liip/Radios